# Конкретная длина строки в SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, table, импорт, length

Как задать параметар ячейки чтоб туда при импорте данных записывалась информация если ее длина равна точно пяти символам и начинается на определенное число, например 2?

Comment: По хорошему эта бизнес логика должна быть на уровне приложения а не на уровне базы. Но если вы хотите, используйте триггеры.

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TRIGGER check_available 
BEFORE INSERT ON table 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
  SELECT IF CHAR_LENGTH(new.StringColunm) <> 5 AND SUBSTRING(new.StringColunm, 1, 1) <> 2) THEN
    SET new.StringColunm = ''
  END IF;
END
```

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: залайкать и пометить :)

Comment: И как это делается? :(

Comment: Нажимаем на стрелки и помечаем ответ как лучший

Comment: Спасибо за отзыв! Голоса от участников с репутацией менее 15 учитываются, но не меняют публично отображаемое значение рейтинга. :(

Comment: А как сделать тоже самое прямо в sql, в смысле с помощию командной строки задать такой параметар колонке?